# Scipy on Python 3.5 - manual installation

Tags: python, scipy

I downloaded `scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe` and tried to install it on WinServer 2008 R2 64bit with Python 3.5 preinstalled. SciPy returns error saying that Python 3.4 not found. My server does not have Internet connection, so I have to download and move files manually. Any suggestions? Should I just try to downgrade to Python 3.4? Is it easy to downgrade?

Comment: Have you tried using [Christoph Gohlke's binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)? I've generally found these to be the best way of installing packages that need a C compiler on Windows. He has a Scipy 0.16.1 Win32 Python 3.5 binary available - `scipy‑0.16.1‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl`.

Comment: I just tried `pip install scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-wi
n32.whl` and got back 
`scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Maybe try the amd64 build instead? Since you're on a 64-bit version of Windows Server. If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: @senshin, It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Christoph Gohlke's binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for Python on Windows are a godsend when you need to install a package that requires a C compiler, like `numpy` or [`scipy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), though he only tends to host binaries for the latest versions of the packages (but for all current versions of CPython).

When installing these binaries, make sure that the platform on the binary (usually `win32` or `win_amd64`) matches the type of Python you installed (32-bit or 64-bit), and note that it may not match your OS's bit-ness if you installed a 32-bit version of Python on a 64-bit OS.

Since you apparently have a 64-bit version of Python 3.5 installed, the wheel you want is `scipy‑0.16.1‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl`.